# Slide out animation with navigation bar in swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uinavigationbar

I need for my project to slide between 3 pages, I have created it and add for each pages one navigation bar.

For go from the first page to the second, I need to use a slide in animation (ok with push modal) and for go from the second page to the first, I need a slide out animation.

http://www.appcoda.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/vid08.gif

My answer is, it is possible to use a slide out animation ( the inverse of the push modal animation ), and is it possible to disabled the animation form the title of the navigation bar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to use Custom View Controller Transition

[Custom Transition](http://www.appcoda.com/custom-view-controller-transitions-tutorial/)

[Worth Reading](http://www.raywenderlich.com/86521/how-to-make-a-view-controller-transition-animation-like-in-the-ping-app)